# SQL: select item only once when filtering by many to many

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many, multiple-tables

I'm having issues with an SQL select statement. I admit I'm a novice, so I apologize in advance for any incorrect terminology.

So I'm trying to select a set up calls that have predetermined tags. The problem I'm facing is that if a call has multiple tags it will return that call for each tag which negates the whole point of what I'm trying to do. I just need some direction on how to use a many to many through table and select each item only once instead of for each tag.

Heres a sample query which works great other than the doupled up calls.

```
SELECT `call`.`id`, `call`.`phone_number`,  COUNT(`call`.`phone_number`) 
FROM `call`
INNER JOIN `call_tag` on `call_tag`.`call_id` = `call`.`call_id`
INNER JOIN `tag` on `tag`.`id` = `call_tag`.`tag_id`
WHERE `tag`.`id` IN (1,2,3)
AND `call`.`phone_number` IN ('4445556666', '6665554444', '8889997777')
AND `call_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01 07:00:00+00:00' and '2015-03-20 05:59:59+00:00'
GROUP BY `call`.`id`
```

I've tried using the Distinctive command but it yielded no changes to my results. I'll be working on this in the mean time and if I find a solution to my problem I'll share it.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Considering you're grouping by the id, you should not be returning duplicates in your posted query.

Comment: You have a `group by`.  It will not return a call multiple times.

Comment: It wouldn't return a phone number multiple times but it would mess with the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix the duplicate issue with a subquery. Looking at your query, it seems like you don't need any data from call_tag or tag so from those tables the following code just returns a distinct list of call ids. I'm somewhat confused about the call.id and call.call_id, are those supposed to be different columns? I also added in call.phone_number to the group by because it should error out without it.

```
SELECT `call`.`id`, `call`.`phone_number`,  COUNT(`call`.`phone_number`) 
FROM `call` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT call_tag.call_id 
                FROM `call_tag` 
                INNER JOIN `tag` 
                    on `tag`.`id` = `call_tag`.`tag_id` 
                WHERE `tag`.`id` IN (1,2,3) 
            ) t
    on t.call_id = `call`.`call_id` 
WHERE `call`.`phone_number` IN ('4445556666', '6665554444', '8889997777') 
AND `call_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01 07:00:00+00:00' and '2015-03-20 05:59:59+00:00' 
GROUP BY `call`.`id`, 'call'.'phone_number'
```

For the count, is the call.id a unique id for every row or does it directly relate to the phone number? I would think you would want to only select the phone number because the id will be unique for each call but I don't know how the data is setup.